# how to show a picture on monitor through VGA from basys3

Tags: vga

I must find a picture and upload it into my basys3 board then I must show it on monitor through VGA cable.
I dont know how to do that.
What are the steps I must take?

Comment: First steps: (1) Don't assume that everyone knows what a "basys3" board is. If this is a something you have bought then it should have a link to a datasheet. If the "basys3" brand name uses capital letters then fix that too. (2) Show what research you have done. We will not do your homework for you but will help if you show some effort which your question does not.

Comment: Find an example for this board, or for another Artix 7 board, or for an FPGA in general.  Start with an example for rendering a frame buffer, then likely one for using an external memory (if applicable) and for accepting data over USB or whatever, then unify them. Neither finding examples nor writing code for you is within the mission of Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

Broad question. A quick summary:

- Whatever image you want to render, you represent that as a pool of digital data , pixel by pixel (known as frame-buffer) in some memory.
- VGA Controller (which you have to design in VHDL/Verilog) will process that data, convert it into R-G-B digital data and generate the corresponding sync signals. Resolution of the image, how many bits representation is needed for one pixel, etc will come into the picture here.
- Finally to drive the VGA display you need a Video-DAC, which converts the RGB digital data from VGA Controller to RGB analog at proper voltage levels. Basys-3 board already has one on it. Refer to the data sheet. You just need to connect the display to the VGA port of Basys-3 then. The display should be supporting the resolution and the sync signals polarity and timing should be correct.